# How to reload collectionView cell when it did end displaying?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a User Onboarding as a `Collection View` with 5 cells (pages).

I have 2 types of Collection View `Items`: `welcomeCell` which is always a first and single cell in Onboarding (`indexPath.item == 0`) and `tutorialCell` (all other cells) which has a `tableView` and can scroll its content vertically.

I want to add the next behaviour:

1. user scrolls `tableView` content and swipes to the next page
2. if user swipes back to the page he scrolled I want the page layout to be reloaded like it was initially set.

For now if a user swipes to the page he scrolled, he will see its position where he ended the scroll.

I suggests that `collectionView` content can be reloaded in `didEndDisplaying` method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item != 0 {
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
}
```

But with this code I receive a strange cells behaviour: I can swipe up `tableView` on one page and the came content position will be on another page, but some page can be loaded with normal content position. Here is a GIF: [GIF](https://cln.sh/wgnjS8)

I also tried `collectionView.reloadData()` in `scrollViewDidScroll` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` but receive the similar behaviour.

Would you be so kind to share some experience and help to understand what's the best practice for my case? Maybe I should find a way to not reload a page content at all, but reload `imageView` height anchor in constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments and information research I ended up with following results:

I slightly modified my initial goal: with below code if user, while swiping, will decide to stay on the current page, then data won't be reloaded. In other cases - reload.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OnboardingCell", for: indexPath) as! OnboardingCollectionViewCell

        // reset the current tableView position to initial one
        if cell.tableView.window != nil {
        cell.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
        cell.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        return cell
}


private var activePage = 0 {
    didSet {
        if activePage != oldValue {
            // the method will fire cellForItemAt code
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
        activePage = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row ?? 0
    }
}
```

Also if you have a navigation controls, like previous and next buttons, don't forget to reload data like so:

```
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with DispatchQueue method:

```
if indexPath.item != 0 {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
  }
```